# Timeout is skipped while executing tests in playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright

[enter image description here][1]Timeout lines in the code are skipped during test runs. 
**Example: **
`await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 3000));`

When I try with locator tobevisible(), it throws error

**Error: timed out 3000ms waiting  for expect(locator).tobevisible()**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcMiW.jpg)

Example:
 `await expect(page1.getByRole('button', { name: 'Add calendar' })).toBeVisible();` (or) 
  `await expect(page1.getByRole('button', { name: 'Add calendar' })).toBeVisible({timeout: 5000});`

Why wouldn't 'await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 3000));' work as expected? Any leads will be helpful.

Code Example:

````ts
     const page1Promise = page.waitForEvent('popup');
      await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'View calendar' }).click();
      const page1 = await page1Promise;
      //await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 3000)); 
      await expect(page1.getByRole('button', { name: 'Add calendar' })).toBeVisible({timeout: 8000});
      // await expect(page1.locator('div').filter({ hasText: /^Add calendar$/ })).toHaveText(/^Add    calendar$/,{timeout: 2000});
     await page1.screenshot({path: 'View Calendar'+Date.now()+'.png', fullPage: true }); ``` <br/>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1YtG.jpg
````

Comment: This was [asked yesterday and closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355356/typescript-timeout-is-skipped-while-executing-the-test-in-playwright) because it was missing details. Posting the same thing again probably won't give you a different result. Why not add a [mcve]? I can't help you without one, and I doubt anyone else can, either. Thanks. Lines of code aren't skipped without an error or reason.

Comment: @ggorlen, The question is pretty forward - 
await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 3000));   are not working. There should be a wait time for 3s after the next line is executed. But its not happening.
FYR, sharing a sample code in the next comment.

Comment: What you're saying is basically impossible. Lines of code can't just get skipped like that, short of a cosmic ray hitting your CPU at the wrong time. There must be some explanation beyond the code you've shown here. (I'm assuming that line isn't commented out as in your snippet, the file is saved, you're executing the right code, etc). In Playwright, you usually don't need to explicitly wait since locators auto-wait anyway, so there are multiple levels of lack of clarity here.

Comment: @ggorlen, I get your point, but its skipped, that's why I have posted to get some help if possible, I have attached a screen shot of the code.
After line 41 we need to capture screen shot. With extra time out/locator/page load commands we can achieve to get the complete screen shot. But that's not happening. So we end up capturing a screenshot while the page is loading.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1YtG.jpg

Comment: Thanks, but the code should be complete, runnable and [posted as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). I shouldn't need to use OCR or have to retype the screenshot to be able to run it and see the line of code being skipped. A [mcve] is especially important when you're essentially suggesting that JavaScript is broken, that it does not run a line of code that is clearly in the main line path of execution. Almost certainly, it's a misunderstanding.

Comment: BTW, I'd use `import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises";` instead of `new Promise`, if you must wait. The code in the screenshot looks OK to me at a glance. I see no reason any lines would be skipped.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you, this helps. It waited for 3s and executed the next step. 
```import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises";``` and 
```await setTimeout(3000); ```

I was able to successfully capture fully loaded screenshot with waitFor() as well. 
```await page1.getByRole('button', { name: 'Add calendar' }).waitFor({ state: 'visible', timeout: 8000 });```
But I am still wondering why await promise line is not picking!!!

Comment: So am I. The `setTimeout` from `node:timers/promises` and `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000))` are equivalent. I only recommend the library one because it's cleaner to look at and less typing, but the functionality should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Playwright has built-in wait methods so you don't really need to use additional wait methods here.

```
const addCalendarButton = "//button[@role='button' and text()='Add calendar']";
await expect(page1.locator(addCalendarButton)).toBeVisible({timeout: 8000});
await page1.screenshot({path: 'View Calendar'+Date.now()+'.png', fullPage: true });
```

Error: timed out 3000ms waiting for expect(locator).tobevisible() means your element didn't appear on a page during this time or your locator is invalid. Please, validate your locator.

You can additionally wait for the selector using something like

```
await page1.waitForSelector(addCalendarButton);
```

Comment: Thank you , the waitForSelector method you suggested worked ! 
-- waitFor state works too. 
```await page1.getByRole('button', { name: 'Add calendar' }).waitFor({ state: 'visible', timeout: 8000 });```